# JDBC Connection Reset when using 64 bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jdbc, rhel

When my server is coming up; it is stuck in getting the connection from oralce DB for 2 mins at the very first time. I think after establishing the first DB connections; JDBC is very quick in getting the next connections.

I have followed the below link

https://community.oracle.com/message/3701989

As per that adding `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom` is resolving my issue.  
Q1) But can i follow this solution? 
Q2) Where is the actual issue, Is it a problem with Sun API OR RedHAt  OR Hardware ? 
Q3) This is not happening in `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)`, why so ..?

There is some good tutorial [here](https://communities.ca.com/web/ca-identity-and-access-mgmt-distributed-global-user-community/message-board?p_auth=lItTump6&p_p_auth=XxziF19G&p_p_id=19&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_19_struts_action=%2Fmessage_boards%2Fget_message_attachment&_19_messageId=101857351&_19_attachment=Entropy_-_Time+%26+Money_2013-11-01_v3.pdf) But i didn't get it.

Comment: What do you mean with 'coming up'? Do you mean after server (or VM) start up, does Oracle run on the same server?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Mark, Yes it is VM start up. No Oracle run on different machine.